# File uploads fail using axios-fetch with Apollo client and apollo-upload-client in Gatsby

Tags: file-upload, gatsby, apollo-client

I'm using `axios-fetch` as a fetch implementation for the Apollo Client in Gatsby. I want to upload files to the server, so I'm using the package: `apollo-upload-client`. But when inspecting the payload that gets sent, it says:

[object FormData], instead of serializing everything.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

**PD**: I tried using `cross-fetch` and it work fine.

**UPDATE:**

This is my Apollo Client creation with `axios-fetch`:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';
import { buildAxiosFetch } from 'axios-fetch'; // This doesn't work
import Axios from 'axios';

import { GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT } from '../settings';

const axios = Axios.create({ timeout: 10000 });
const fetch = buildAxiosFetch(axios);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  link: new (createUploadLink as any)({
    uri: GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
    fetch,
  }),
});

export default client;
```

Comment: Can you share the corresponding snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using serializing the data using `JSON.stringify`?

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  link: new (createUploadLink as any)({
    uri: GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
    JSON.stringify(fetch),
  }),
});
```